# Weird issue in C

Tags: c

thanks for your help.

I'm trying to similate a simplified version of ARM, and I have a very weird error in c http://pastebin.com/3XRdngty .
I don't understant why in the function executer_code(), 
the for doesn't work ...
I mean it should be looping untill the variable "i" is equal to the variable nombre_instruction, 
but it turns out that the variable "nombre_instruction" is the right value the first time it goes in
 the for, but the second time it doesn't go in the for because its value changed to 0,
 I search on the internet if someone has the same kind of error, 
and i didn't find anything.
I reread my code but still I cannot figure out why it does this, 3 hours has passed already.
And thank you again for you help :)

Comment: probably not the sole problem (I didn't try to run your code yet), but your `nombre_instructions` variable is not initialized. This is surely asking for trouble, especially as it is used as an array index.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in text form, within your question (not an external link). Please also see: [ask].

Comment: Did you try step-by-step debugging ?

Comment: You have multiple Undefined Behaviors in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from your code:

```
char *compar;
if(i==0){
    sprintf(&compar,"%c%c%c%c",code[0],code[1],code[2],code[3]);
}
```

The problem here is that you declare `compar` as a pointer to `char`, but it is uninitialized. So, it has an undefined value. When you fill it with `sprintf`, you just write somewhere in the memory, and apparently, you write over the variable `nombre_instruction`.

Solution:

```
char compar[200];
```